# A short "RewriteRule" regexp question

Tags: php, html, regex, apache, .htaccess

I have a very very long querystring which ALWAYS starts like this:

```
  mydomain.com/bincgi/sql_query.php?alot alot alot of variables passed along
```

What is the regular expression to make a rewriteRule if I want to pass along all the variables but via this link:

```
  mydomain.com/search/all variables here instead.....
```

So the last one is what I intend to write as a link, but the "REAL" link is the first one...

Simplified put, I need to replace the `/bincgi/sql_query.php` with `/search/`

Hope you understand what I am looking for...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?search/?$ bincgi/sql_query.php [QSA,L]
```

The QSA (query string append) will handle the query string for you, no need to mess with it manually.

Comment: This wont work... When I set the form action to "/search/" instead of "bincgi/sql_query.php" I receive nothing, it is like the page gets refreshed...

Comment: I just edited my answer, you want search/ to rewrite to bincgi/sql_query.php, correct?